# How to create kml to geocode addresses in Google Earth?

Tags: excel, geocoding, kml, google-earth, vba

If you have a .csv file with address information in it, you can drag/drop it onto the Google Earth (henceforth referred to as GE) and a wizard will come up so you can assign fields and GE will then start geocoding the locations and create points (latitude and longitude) for each address. You can then export the geocoded file as a kml and get the lat/long for each point. This process however has a limit of 2500 rows.

I have heard that a kml (or maybe an xml) file can be created and pulled into GE to start the geocoding process and that this method doesn't have a row limit. Can someone please help me figure out how to do this? I have tried the following code, which does successfully import into GE but no points are created.

I am aware of some Google Maps API that can do something similar and has a row limit of 100,000 rows a day for business use but I would really like to get the process working with GE.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
<Document>
    <name>GEImport1.csv</name>
    <Schema name="GEImport1" id="S_GEImport1_S">
        <SimpleField type="string" name="Adress"><displayName>&lt;b&gt;Adress&lt;/b&gt;</displayName>
</SimpleField>
    </Schema>
    <Style id="hlightPointStyle">
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle_highlight.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
            <text><![CDATA[<table border="0">
  <tr><td><b>Adress</b></td><td>$[GEImport1/Adress]</td></tr>
</table>
]]></text>
        </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <Style id="normPointStyle">
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
            <text><![CDATA[<table border="0">
  <tr><td><b>Adress</b></td><td>$[GEImport1/Adress]</td></tr>
</table>
]]></text>
        </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="pointStyleMap">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#normPointStyle</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
        <Pair>
            <key>highlight</key>
            <styleUrl>#hlightPointStyle</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Folder id="layer 0">
        <name>GEImport1</name>
        <visibility>0</visibility>
        <Placemark>
            <visibility>0</visibility>
            <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <SchemaData schemaUrl="#S_GEImport1_S">
                    <SimpleData name="Adress">6212 GATUN CT Port ST Lucie, FL</SimpleData>
                </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <visibility>0</visibility>
            <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <SchemaData schemaUrl="#S_GEImport1_S">
                    <SimpleData name="Adress">6213 DIANA CT Port ST Lucie, FL</SimpleData>
                </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <visibility>0</visibility>
            <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>
            <ExtendedData>
                <SchemaData schemaUrl="#S_GEImport1_S">
                    <SimpleData name="Adress">6213 DUKE CIR Port ST Lucie, FL</SimpleData>
                </SchemaData>
            </ExtendedData>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

**Edit: Final Result**
JasonM1's solutions worked great!
I ended up with the following format for the kml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2" xmlns:kml="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom">
    <Document>
<name>AddressImport</name>
    <Style id="normPointStyle">
        <IconStyle>
            <Icon>
                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png</href>
            </Icon>
        </IconStyle>
        <BalloonStyle>
            <text><![CDATA[<table border="0">
          <tr><td><b>Address</b></td><td>$[address]</td></tr>
          </table>]]>
      </text>
        </BalloonStyle>
    </Style>
    <StyleMap id="pointStyleMap">
        <Pair>
            <key>normal</key>
            <styleUrl>#normPointStyle</styleUrl>
        </Pair>
    </StyleMap>
    <Folder id="layer 0">
        <name>AddressImport</name>
        <visibility>1</visibility>
        <Placemark>
            <visibility>1</visibility>
            <address>9994 CHADWICK DR Port ST Lucie, FL</address>
            <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <visibility>1</visibility>
            <address>9995 AMBROSE WAY Port ST Lucie, FL</address>
            <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>
        </Placemark>
        <Placemark>
            <visibility>1</visibility>
            <address>9997 STONEGATE DR Port ST Lucie, FL</address>
            <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>
        </Placemark>
    </Folder>
</Document>
</kml>
```

Also, I used the following Excel VBA code to automatically create the kml file:

```
Sub CreateCSV_FSO()
    Dim objFSO
    Dim objTF
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim lCol As Long
    Dim strTmp As String
    Dim lFnum As Long
    Dim sFilePath As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim x As Integer 'used to represent the column that contains the address
    sFilePath = ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\AddressImport.kml"

    Set objFSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
    Set objTF = objFSO.createtextfile(sFilePath, True, False)

    'Header information
    objTF.writeline "<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>"
    objTF.writeline "<kml xmlns=""http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"" xmlns:gx=""http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2"" xmlns:kml=""http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"" xmlns:atom=""http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"">"
    objTF.writeline "    <Document>"
    objTF.writeline "<name>AddressImport</name>"
    objTF.writeline "    <Style id=""normPointStyle"">"
    objTF.writeline "        <IconStyle>"
    objTF.writeline "            <Icon>"
    objTF.writeline "                <href>http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/placemark_circle.png</href>"
    objTF.writeline "            </Icon>"
    objTF.writeline "        </IconStyle>"
    objTF.writeline "        <BalloonStyle>"
    objTF.writeline "            <text><![CDATA[<table border=""0"">"
    objTF.writeline "          <tr><td><b>Address</b></td><td>$[address]</td></tr>"
    objTF.writeline "          </table>]]>"
    objTF.writeline "      </text>"
    objTF.writeline "        </BalloonStyle>"
    objTF.writeline "    </Style>"
    objTF.writeline "    <StyleMap id=""pointStyleMap"">"
    objTF.writeline "        <Pair>"
    objTF.writeline "            <key>normal</key>"
    objTF.writeline "            <styleUrl>#normPointStyle</styleUrl>"
    objTF.writeline "        </Pair>"
    objTF.writeline "    </StyleMap>"
    objTF.writeline "    <Folder id=""layer 0"">"
    objTF.writeline "        <name>AddressImport</name>"
    objTF.writeline "        <visibility>1</visibility>"

    'input the number representative of the column that contains the address
    x = 7 'a=1,b=2,c=3,d=4.....etc.
    i = 2
    While Cells(i, x) <> ""

        strTmp = ""
        strTmp = Cells(i, x)
        strTmp = Replace(strTmp, "&", "and")

        objTF.writeline "        <Placemark>"
        objTF.writeline "            <visibility>1</visibility>"
        objTF.writeline "            <address>" & strTmp & "</address>"
        objTF.writeline "            <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>"
        objTF.writeline "        </Placemark>"


        strTmp = Cells(i, x)
        i = i + 1
    Wend

    objTF.writeline "    </Folder>"
    objTF.writeline "</Document>"
    objTF.writeline "</kml>"


    objTF.Close
    Set objFSO = Nothing
    MsgBox "Done!", vbOKOnly

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the <[address](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference#address)> element in KML in which Google Earth will geocode the address automatically for you.

```
<Placemark>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
    <address>6213 DUKE CIR Port ST Lucie, FL</address>
    <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>             
</Placemark>
```

You can use the `<address>` tag to specify the location of a point instead of using latitude and longitude coordinates. (However, if a `<Point>` is provided, it takes precedence over the `<address>`.)

Also, you no longer would need the Schema and *Adress* SchemaData elements but can directly inline the *$[address]* field in the BalloonStyle text:

```
<BalloonStyle>
      <text><![CDATA[<table border="0">
          <tr><td><b>Adress</b></td><td>$[address]</td></tr>
          </table>]]>
      </text>
</BalloonStyle>
```

After you load the KML file in Google Earth and save it, you'll notice that Google Earth will change it to the following with the coordinates filled-in:

```
<Placemark>
    <address>6213 DUKE CIR Port ST Lucie, FL</address>
    <styleUrl>#pointStyleMap</styleUrl>
    <MultiGeometry>
        <Point>
            <coordinates>-80.36086,27.366379,0</coordinates>
        </Point>
        <LinearRing>
            <coordinates>
                -80.36086,27.366379,0 -80.36086,27.366379,0 -80.36086,27.366379,0 -80.36086,27.366379,0 -80.36086,27.366379,0 
            </coordinates>
        </LinearRing>
    </MultiGeometry>
</Placemark>
```